# Highlighting Current Page Menu Tab Using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

Can someone please offer me some advice?

I'm trying to customise a website and its HTML Nav Menu. By default, the menu already highlights the current tab for all existing pre-built pages.

http://webservices.retrotorque.com

I've added a new page to the website - Website Design - and I've added a tab to the menu for that page. All fine. But I can't find a way of making that tab become highlighted for only when that page is viewed.

Here is the existing code for one of the default tabs, which works fine.

```
<li class="first <#tag:homesection /#>">
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Here's my code for the menu tab I've created for my new page:

```
<li class="levelone <#tag:webdesignsection /#> ">
<a href="/websitedesign.html">Website Design</a>          
<li>
```

My problem is that I can't find where to define:

```
<#tag:webdesignsection /#>
```

So I may need to find another solution.

I've thought of another approach:

```
<li class="levelone active">
<a href="/websitedesign.html">Website Design</a>          
<li>
```

This code does work, but only in so much as the tab is always highlighted, whichever page is being viewed.

Is there a way of wrapping this up in a 'conditional'? So that it only applies when viewing the websitedesign page. And I could have a non-active alternative, conditionally set up for when viewing any of the other pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put JQuery there that can addClass and removeClass active from li element.
there is for example

```
var url = document.URL;
$('#example li a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried the code. And I've also tried a few variations I've found via other answers. I'm sure it's close, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The original header code already contains JQuery code, which functions correctly. I've done some experimentation, and it seems it's the '.parent' term which isn't having any affect. I can't work out why.